# How to access SAP Fiori Launchpad with SAP Fiori Client Android App? throws SSL error

Tags: ssl-certificate, sap-fiori

I am facing this SSL error with SAP Fiori:

> Server's Certificate Not Trusted

If anyone faced this same issue and cleared, kindly suggest.

[image: Error Screen shot attached]

Answer (score 0):

the screenshot doesn't tell much, but you're opening an ip, which returns a certificate which is valid for a hostname. try to replace the ip with hostname in the url, and if it resolves correctly and your browser trusts the certificate issuer, it should display the FLP login.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same problem, SAP Fiori Client need a valid certificate to connect. You can't bypass it.

Comment: With a web browser, you can bypass the certificat error